How to properly set up App Bars with StatefulShellRoutes used for a common Bottom Nav bar?
I am new to flutter and am creating my first application. It has a couple onboarding screens, and then after authentication takes the user to a StatefulShellRoute.indexedStack() which wraps child pages in a wrapper widget with a bottom nav bar (I call it TabBarNavigationPage). In this wrapper widget, I build a scaffold with a bottom nav bar and an appbar as well since i want the app bar visible on all authenticated pages in the app.
class _TabBarNavigationPageState extends State<TabBarNavigationPage> {
  final List<String> appBarTitles = ['Videos', 'Profile'];
  final List<String> poppableRoutes = ['/videos/single-video'];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(appBarTitles[widget.child.currentIndex]),
          centerTitle: true,
          actions: const [
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
              child: ImageIcon(
                AssetImage('assets/images/logo.png'),
                color: Color.fromRGBO(245, 144, 66, 1),
                size: 40,
              ),
            ),
          ],
          leading: poppableRoutes.contains(GoRouterState.of(context).fullPath)
              ? IconButton(onPressed: () => context.pop(), icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back))
              : null),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: widget.child,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        currentIndex: widget.child.currentIndex,
        onTap: (index) {
          widget.child.goBranch(
            index,
            initialLocation: index == widget.child.currentIndex,
          );
          setState(() {});
        },
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.play_arrow), label: 'Videos'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle), label: 'Profile')
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

For context, here is my StatefulShellRoute.indexedStack:
StatefulShellRoute.indexedStack(
            parentNavigatorKey: rootNavigatorKey,
            branches: [
              StatefulShellBranch(
                  navigatorKey: videosNavigatorKey,
                  initialLocation: '/videos',
                  routes: [
                    GoRoute(
                        path: '/videos',
                        name: 'videos',
                        routes: [
                          GoRoute(
                              path: 'single-video',
                              name: 'single-video',
                              pageBuilder: (context, state) {
                                return getPage(
                                    child: const SingleVideoScreen(),
                                    state: state);
                              }),
                        ],
                        pageBuilder: (context, state) {
                          return getPage(
                              child: const VideosScreen(), state: state);
                        }),
                  ]),
              StatefulShellBranch(navigatorKey: profileNavigatorKey, routes: [
                GoRoute(
                    path: '/profile',
                    name: 'profile',
                    pageBuilder: (context, state) {
                      return getPage(
                          child: const ProfileScreen(), state: state);
                    })
              ])
            ],
            pageBuilder: (context, state, navigationShell) {
              return getPage(
                  child: TabBarNavigationPage(child: navigationShell),
                  state: state);
            })

In the 'Videos' branch of my StatefulShellRoute, I have a 'single-video' screen which is pushed onto the current navigation stack using context.go(), so I need to have a back button to take a user back to the main videos page.
My question is, is this a correct way to set up a common app bar and back button? I am doubting this approach due to my weird way of deciding whether or not to display a 'back' button in the TabBarNavigationPage, as checking to see if the current route is poppable based on a hardcoded list is hacky.
Based on Flutter docs for AppBar and BackButton, I tried a series of solutions of explicitly providing BackButton, not providing it and setting automaticallyImplyLeading to true, and using context.push() instead of context.go().
